# datatable search field always focus stop all other action

Tags: jquery, datatable

my datatable search field focus always ,but it stop all other action ,is it possible that focus reamin in search field and other action also work ?

my code for focus is as

```
var table = $('#datatable').dataTable({   
           "bJQueryUI": true,           
           "stateSave": false,                      
           "bProcessing": true,
           "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
           "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
           "iDisplayLength": -1
        });
        $('#datatable_filter input').focus()

        $('#datatable_filter input').on('blur', function(){
         $('#datatable_filter input').focus() 
        });
```

i also try timeout that not work

```
$('#datatable_filter input').on('blur', function () { 
        setTimeout(function () { $('#datatable_filter input').focus(); }, 1000);
         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set focus in field on window.focus() as:

```
    $(window).on('focus', function(){
     $('#datatable_filter input').focus() 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

i found my answer and it work for me

```
$('#datatable_filter input').focus()
        $(window).on('focus', function(){
         $('#datatable_filter input').focus() 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with this code to focus search box

```
$('div.dataTables_filter input').focus();
```

Comment: my question is that my focus work but another action not work properly.from your code same work.